# How to automatically rename SPECIFIC item in hand in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im trying to find command to rename handheld item(s) to something without giving another item(s). For example rename "Seed"(s) to "123".

Comment: I would suggest you make questions longer and more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

## Impossible.

You cannot `/entitydata` a player, nor can you `/entitydata` a specific inventory item. You'll have to `/clear` it out and `/give` a new one with the altered name.

`/clear` allows you to specify NBT tags as well.

(This is assuming Vanilla Minecraft)

Answer (score -3):

I think a know what your trying to say, I would suggest you a scoreboard and detect that using the scoreboard... then clear that item, and give your "123" named seed in its place

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to suggest here. Could you please edit your post using the "edit" button (near the bottom left) to try to make it a bit more clear? Thanks!